# Cypher, get all nodes with and relationships for a given label without duplicates, empty relationships or empty nodes

Tags: d3.js, neo4j, cypher

I'm new to Neo4j and am having problems getting the data back I need. I'm working on a visualisation project of social networks. I want to get all the Connections and relationships (CONNECTED_TO) based on the id of the root node so I can then loop over the data and build up a data structure for D3.

[Current Schema Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUXrQ.png)

I've tried playing around with a lot of queries in the browser. The current one returns the correct result in the browser with auto complete off but the result that's returned in NodeJS returns duplicates and empty relationships.

```
MATCH p=(a:Connection)-[r:CONNECTED_TO]-(b:Connection)-[r2:CONNECTED_TO]-()
WHERE id(a) = 1673
RETURN [a, b] as nodes [r, r2]
```

The below statement returns what I want it just doesn't have the WHERE clause. When the where clause is added it only returns the root Connection and the their immediate connections without the all the relationships

```
MATCH (a:Connection)-[r:CONNECTED_TO]-(b:Connection)
RETURN [a, b] AS nodes, r AS relationship
```

The dataset of medium side with about 200 Connections and 2200 relationships so performance is also and issue to bear in mind.

Any help would be of great appreciation.

UPDATE

The APOC path expansion procedure suggested by InverseFalcon works excellently. It's very efficient compared to using variable length relationships.

Here's the resulting query

```
MATCH (head:Connection)
WHERE id(head) = 1673
CALL apoc.path.expandConfig(head, {relationshipFilter:'CONNECTED_TO', uniqueness:'NODE_GLOBAL', bfs: true}) YIELD path
WITH LAST(NODES(path)) as a
MATCH (a)-[r:CONNECTED_TO]->(b)
RETURN [a, b] as nodes, r as relationship
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to find the entire network for a user, and then from those nodes in the network, output each pairing of nodes connected by a :CONNECTED_TO relationship.

When using a MATCH with [variable-length relationships](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/patterns/#_variable_length), all paths are explored, which will lead to a build up of redundant relationships, and may blow up on a sufficiently large network.

APOC Procedures has an efficient way to expand all nodes of a subgraph with its [path expansion procedure](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_expand_paths). Once we have all connection nodes in the network, we can match on the nodes they are connected to, and output the two nodes along with the connecting relationship.

Also, from your description of empty relationships, it sounds like few if any of these relationships have properties. The textual output for relationships without properties is an empty map, {}, though in the code itself, there should be relationship id and type data available.

If you do want to explicitly return the type of the relationship along with its attributes, you can use [map projection](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/lists/#_map_projection) to include the type of the relationship along with the rest of its attributes.

The full query might look like this:

```
MATCH (head:Connection)
WHERE id(head) = 1673
CALL apoc.path.expandConfig(head, {relationshipFilter:'CONNECTED_TO>', uniqueness:'NODE_GLOBAL'}) YIELD path
WITH LAST(NODES(path)) as a
MATCH (a)-[r:CONNECTED_TO]->(b)
RETURN [a, b] as nodes, r {TYPE(r), .*} as relationship
```

Comment: Excellent answer InverseFalcon, very well put together. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Some of the APOC procedures will work really well with other functionality I have planned for this project.